# TFS: not all agent machines run (any) tests during build

Tags: tfs

We have a set of approximately 1000 (currently) tests, written in C#, that run twice a week.  We are using TFS 2017 update 1 (on-premise), and the system is configured to run tests on 6 VMs that are set up on another machine.  4 of those VMs are running Windows Server 2012R2, and the other 2 are Windows Server 2016.  All are fully up-to-date with updates.  Development is done using VS 2017.  All tests are straight, non-UI functional tests that use instances of SQL server on each machine, with no cross-machine communication or anything like that during tests.  Each machine is its own self-contained environment.

All the tests run fine locally (or if they fail we know why and that's fine).  When we launch a build, the actual build and other preliminary steps seem to go fine.  When it gets to the "Run Functional Tests" step, though, only SOME of the agent machines begin running them, typically 2 of the 6, sometimes 3, and not usually the same ones.  Looking at Task Manager I can see that the other VMs have no processor activity to speak of.  I have no idea why this should be, or why it seems to be different machines that successfully fire up and begin running tests from run to run.

The kicker is that because all machines are not running, this puts us over the 6 hour limit test run limit, which I have seen dealt with in other threads....I have tried everything suggested in those threads (including the setting in the .runsettings file) and can't get it to let go of that timeout, and so our whole run cancels after 6 hours with a lot of the tests aborted.  For some reason last week we got a clean run of all the tests...nothing had changed since the prior run, and it reverted to this behavior with the next run.

Any insight on either the "lazy" machines not running tests OR removing the 6 hour timeout would be much appreciated...

Additional note:  this behavior started "out of the blue", on or about August 9.  Until then, all machines performed as desired.  No software upgrades or anything else suspect happened anywhere near that time.  Though the 6-hour time limit thing has been bugging me for a year or so.

Comment: Did you select the "Distribute tests by number of machines" in your Run Functional Tests build task?

Comment: I discovered the "Distribute Tests by Number of Machines" setting, I believe when we upgraded to 2017, and it has been set ever since. Both the runTimeout and testTimeout settings are set to a week in the testsettings file, and there is a reference to the testsettings file in the runsettings file.

Comment: What's the settings for VisualStudio Test Agent Deployment task and Run Functional Test task? Can you share a screenshot for them and the build logs for these two tasks?

Answer (score 0):

There is an Execution Options called **Distribute tests by number of machines**.

> Instead of distributing tests at the assembly level, enabling this
>   setting will distribute tests based on the number of machines
>   irrespective of the container assemblies given to the task.
>
> [Source Link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/06/21/remote-testing-distributing-tests-based-on-number-of-machines/)

Note: that tests within a dll might also be distributed to multiple machines.

---

To bypass the 6 hours limitation, you could set the runTimeout to xx hours in ***`testsettings`*** files and should be able to run tests more than 6 hours on successfully.

```
<Execution>
   <Timeouts runTimeout="36000000" testTimeout="5400000" />
   <AgentRule name="Execution Agents">
   </AgentRule>
</Execution>
```

More details please refer the answer in this thread: [TFS 2015 vNext : Test Run always abort after 6 hours](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/84907a89-e6dd-4402-86b6-2acbec13be44/tfs-2015-vnext-test-run-always-abort-after-6-hours?forum=tfsbuild)

Comment: I did, by the way, find that thread some time ago, and read through it entirely.  Nothing seemed to help the 6-hour issue.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after going back through everything thoroughly, I discovered that there were actually TWO problems in my setup.  The elusive one was that my runsettings file did NOT have the ForcedLegacyMode=True, which is apparently necessary for it to even look for the testsettings file.  Once I corrected that, I discovered that it was not correctly pointing to my testsettings file.  There is a further problem after that in that it's not discovering any tests now, but I think that might be due to a different problem, so I suspect the problem as originally stated is now resolved.  Thanks for the suggestions!